# Cloudfront path mappings serve content rather than redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

The Cloudfront distribution is setup with API gateway and S3 bucket in the origins and path behavior mapped to each of them.

*screenshot of sample origins*:

[image: Origins Sample Screen shot]

*and behaviors * [image: Behavior Path Mapping]

The Cloudfront url serves both the s3 bucket and the API gateway. Except, the only issue is the url is redirected in case of API gateway.

Example: lets assume dev.cloudfront.net is the cloudfront url.
when I access dev.cloudfront.net it serves the s3 bucket contents, but when i access dev.cloudfront.net/v2/ducks, it redirects to rfgxqi5z8g.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ducks instead of serving it on the cloudfront url.

Flow Currently:

```
dev.cloudfront.net (CF) -> dev.cloudfront.net/ (S3 Bucket Contents)
dev.cloudfront.net/v2/ducks (CF)-> rfgxqi5z8g.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ducks (API)
```

Flow Expecting:

```
dev.cloudfront.net/v2/ducks (CF) -> dev.cloudfront.net/v2/ducks (API)
```

Is there a way I can serve the content on the same cloudfront url instead of redirection?

Comment: Is this the same if you're using HTTPS, is the custom domain for that URL valid for the CloudFront distribution you're using

Comment: It's most likely whatever is behind API gateway doing the redirect

Comment: @Chris Williams It was all on HTTPS only before I changed them to match viewer, the custom domain url does point correctly else i wouldn't be able to see the S3 page.

Comment: It's currently set up as an origin fetch not redirect.